# Log Django command output to Apache error log

Tags: python, django, apache, logging

How do I get log output from my custom Django commands in to the Apache logs?

In settings.py, I have the logger set to log to the console, as that is the only way I've found to get the Django app to write logs to the Apache log.  However, if I then use the app logger within a Django command and run that command from the command line (e.g. `python manage.py my_command`), the logging set up writes to the actual console instead of the Apache log.

Can I configure the logging differently, or even call the Django command differently, to get the command logging to write to the Apache log?

settings.py logging snippet:

```
'handlers' : {
    'console':{ #this logs to the Apache log when called from within the Django app e.g. from within views.py
         'level':'INFO',
         'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
         'formatter':'standard',
    }
}
....
'loggers' : {
    'app_logger': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level':'DEBUG',
    }
}
```

my_command.py snippet:

```
....
class Command(BaseCommand):
    ....
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # do some useful work here
        log = logging.getLogger("app_logger")
        # when called from the command line, this statement is logged back to the console, not the Apache log
        log.info("something happened")
```

Comment: Why would a command, which is being run from the command line and not under Apache, log to the Apache log?

Comment: so that all logging is in the same place :-)